# Add dotlottie packge to Nuxt3

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, lottie

I want to add the dotlottie web player dependency to a nuxt3 application to play lottie animations on a page.

The dotlottie webplayer documentation only provides a guide on adding the library to nuxt 2[1]. How can I add the dotlottie webplayer to a nuxt 3 application?

I have tried creating a plugin to load dotlottie on the client side.

`dotlottie-player.client.js`

```js
import '@dotlottie/player-component'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(DotLottiePlayer)
})
```

`index.vue`

```js
<template>
    <section>
        <div>
            <dotlottie-player
                src="~/assets/graphics/programmer.lottie"
                autoplay
                loop
            />
        </div>
    </section>
</template>
```

However, this does not work and returns the following errors.
[image: Error log from Firefox console]

[1] https://docs.lottiefiles.com/dotlottie-player/usage#usage-example-in-nuxtjs-vuejs

Comment: Do you still get the same issue with a correct import statement in your plugin?
`import * as LottiePlayer from '@dotlottie/player-component'`
`nuxtApp.vueApp.use(LottiePlayer)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

so in your plugins folder.

```
// lottie-player.client.js
// IMPORTANT notice the .client bit
import * as LottiePlayer from "@dotlottie/player-component";
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(LottiePlayer);
});
```

then you use it like so:

```
<dotlottie-player :src="`URL`" autoplay loop />
```

Comment: This gives the warning: "[Vue warn]: A plugin must either be a function or an object with an "install" function."

Answer (score 0):

LottiePlayer has an `vue` package: https://github.com/LottieFiles/lottie-vue

Install it `npm install --save @lottiefiles/vue-lottie-player`

And create a new Nuxt Plugin for it in `plugins/lottie.ts`

```
import * as LottiePlayer from '@lottiefiles/vue-lottie-player';

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(LottiePlayer)
})
```